# Expected type-specifier before ')' token c++

Tags: c++

I am trying to overload the "<<" operator to print out a structure I made. The structure is a hashed array tree. I have a "HashNode" class that performs all the operations on nodes of a hash tree and I overload the operator in the class. I have a MLH class which instantiates a single HashNode. Here is the relevant code:

HashNode.cpp

```
template <typename T>
ostream &operator << ( ostream &output, const HashNode<T> &node ) {
  if(node.stemNode == 0){
    //leaf node                                                                               
    for(int i=0; i < node.numElements; i++) {
      output << "\n-------------------------------------------" << endl;
      output << "This Node's Level: " << node.nodeLevel << endl;
      output << "\nKey: " << node.keyArray[i] << endl;
      output << "\nData: " << *(node.dataArray[i])  << endl;
    }
    output << "\n\n";
  }else if (node.stemNode == 1) {
    //stem node                                                                               
    for(int j=0; j<5; j++) {
      if(node.childArray[j] != NULL) {
        output << *(node.childArray[j]);
        // levelCtr++;                                                                   
      }
    }
  }
  int lowest;
  int ctr = 0;
  for(int i = 8; i>=0; i--) {
    if(levels[i]==0) {
      ctr++;
    }
  }
  lowest = 9-(ctr+1);
  if(node.nodeLevel == 0) {
    output << "\n\nLowest Level: " << (9-(ctr+1)) << endl;
  }
  return output; //<< "\n\nLowest Level: " << lowest <<   endl;                                   
}
```

MLH.cpp

```
template <typename T>
ostream &operator << (ostream &output, const MLH<T> &tree)
{
  //HashNode<T> ptr = tree;                                                       
  output << *(tree->proot->operator);
  return output;
}
```

For some reason, I get the following error when trying to compile:

```
g++ -c -g Hashtest.cpp
In file included from Hashtest.cpp:2:0:
MLH.h: In function ‘std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream&, const MLH<T>&)’:
MLH.h:69:36: error: expected type-specifier before ‘)’ token
output << *(tree->proot->operator);
                             ^
make: *** [Hashtest.o] Error 1
```

If I am returning the output stream from the HashNode class to the output stream in the MLH class, why is there an issue? Thanks for the help and I apologize for any formatting issues.

EDIT: I should have specified that "proot" is an attribute of an MLH object. It is a pointer to a HashNode object. By saying "tree->proot->operator", I am trying to call the overloading operator function in the HashNode class.

Comment: What is `tree->proot->operator` supposed to mean?

Comment: Did you mean `output << *(tree->proot);` ??

Comment: Isn't `operator` a reserved keyword?

Comment: `output << *(tree->proot->operator);` Which operator are you trying to use there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
output << *(tree->proot->operator);
```

That's not how to call the overloaded << operator. This is how:

```
template <typename T>
ostream &operator << (ostream &output, const MLH<T> &tree)
{                                               
    output << *(tree->proot);  // Assuming tree->proot is a HashNode<T> pointer
    return output;
}
```